# How to change label on ggplot2 to hover in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

So I currently have my data which looks like this.

```
structure(list(Reportable = c("Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", 
"Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", "Non-Reportable Injury", 
"Reportable Injury", "Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", 
"Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", "Non-Reportable Injury", 
"Reportable Injury", "Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", 
"Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", "Non-Reportable Injury", 
"Reportable Injury", "Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury", 
"Non-Reportable Injury", "Reportable Injury"), Result_Description = c("OTHER", 
"OTHER", "GROUND", "GROUND", "DOOR", 
"DOOR", "STAIR STEP", "STAIR STEP", "FLOOR", "FLOOR", "CHAIR/SEAT", 
"CHAIR/SEAT", "LOCOMOTIVE, OTHER", "LOCOMOTIVE, OTHER", "BALLAST, STONES, ETC.", 
"BALLAST, STONES, ETC.", "DOOR, TRAP - PASSENGER TRAIN", "DOOR, TRAP - PASSENGER TRAIN", 
"PLATFORM", "PLATFORM", "TRACK (RAIL)", "TRACK (RAIL)"), count = c(69L, 
235L, 27L, 91L, 29L, 44L, 19L, 39L, 14L, 38L, 15L, 31L, 21L, 
25L, 16L, 27L, 15L, 22L, 8L, 25L, 4L, 26L), pct = c("23%", "77%", 
"23%", "77%", "40%", "60%", "33%", "67%", "27%", "73%", "32%", 
"66%", "45.7%", "54.3%", "37%", "63%", "41%", "59%", "24%", "76%", 
"13%", "87%"), total = c("69 (23%)", "235 (77%)", "27 (23%)", 
"91 (77%)", "29 (40%)", "44 (60%)", "19 (33%)", "39 (67%)", "14 (27%)", 
"38 (73%)", "15 (32%)", "31 (66%)", "21 (45.7%)", "25 (54.3%)", 
"16 (37%)", "27 (63%)", "15 (41%)", "22 (59%)", "8 (24%)", "25 (76%)", 
"4 (13%)", "26 (87%)"), total1 = c("69\n(23%)", "235\n(77%)", 
"27\n(23%)", "91\n(77%)", "29\n(40%)", "44\n(60%)", "19\n(33%)", 
"39\n(67%)", "14\n(27%)", "38\n(73%)", "15\n(32%)", "31\n(66%)", 
"21\n(45.7%)", "25\n(54.3%)", "16\n(37%)", "27\n(63%)", "15\n(41%)", 
"22\n(59%)", "8\n(24%)", "25\n(76%)", "4\n(13%)", "26\n(87%)"
)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And I plot it as follows:

```
ggplot(Result_counts, aes(fill=Reportable, y=count, x=as.factor(Result_Description), label = total)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(Result_Description), 40), count) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Injury Count", fill = "")+
 geom_text(size = 2, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  ggtitle("Injury Plot")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorange", "cornflowerblue") ) +
  theme_hc() +
  coord_flip()
```

Cool right?

I have been messing around with `plotly` and more importantly `ggplotly` so remove my in-bar labels and instead have the labels appear on hover.

So how can I make this change to my ggplot code.

Once this is complete I still want to have a total on the right of each bar as a label which indicates sum of counts and percent of each full bar, irrespective of `Reportable`.

So basically two goals

1. Change existing labels to hovers
2. Add a new label for the actual total count and percent of whole for each bar.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your initial dataframe above as `df`.  Then the code below

```
b <- aggregate(df$count, by=list(a=df$Result_Description), FUN=sum)
  names(b) <- c("Result_Description","fullcount")
  Result_counts <- left_join(df,b,by="Result_Description")
  
  p <- ggplot(Result_counts, 
              aes(fill=Reportable, y=count, x=as.factor(Result_Description), 
                  text=paste(Reportable, ": ", total) )) +
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
    aes(stringr::str_wrap(as.factor(Result_Description), 40), count) +
    labs(x = "", y = "Injury Count", fill = "")+
    geom_text(aes(label = fullcount, y = fullcount, vjust = 0.5)) +
    ggtitle("Injury Plot")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkorange", "cornflowerblue") ) +
    theme_hc() +
    coord_flip()
  
  pp <- ggplotly(p, tooltip=c("text"))
  pp
```

gives this output:

[image: output]

Comment: Okay this is close. However It says total on each which isn't correct per say. I would like it to say "Reportable Injury: XX" when it's a hover on blue, and similarly for orange.

Comment: @JohnThomas, Please see the updated code and output. You can modify what you want to display in hover via `text` definition in `ggplot`.